# Tooltips on materialDesign:PackIcon not displaying when mouse is over pixels not drawned

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I'm facing a problem with Tooltips not displaying sometimes using materialDesign:PackIcon library.

When the mouse is over a transparent pixel (not drawned) of an icon, the tooltip is not displayed. Otherwise it is well displayed.

This is my sample :

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="SmileyHappy"/>
```

Comment: Can you please post what steps you have taken to work around this and debug?

Comment: @Nik P, I'm sorry but don't know what I can explain more, otherwise put scrennshots.

Comment: @Nik P, the question description was enough clear. It's not necessary to put wide descriptions into a question to be valid. More the question is concise more it's easily readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default background of the PackIcon is unset.

Take a look at this example :

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon Height="20" Width="20" Kind="LinkVariant" 
    Foreground="Gray"
    ToolTip="My text"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Background="Transparent"
/>
```

Comment: thank you I tried it, it's working.